# Merge multiple Ruby hash attributes

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a few objects that each have an `ids` attribute that is a hash of id's. For example, `person_1.ids` is `{id1: "1", id2: "2"}`, `person_2.ids` is `{id1: "3", id2: "4"}`, `person_3.ids` is `{id1: "5", id2: "6"}`. What is the cleanest way that I can go from a collection (or array) of these objects (say `persons`) to a single hash of the form `{ id1: "1,3,5", id2: "2,4,6" }`.

Comment: Why not write `persons` in your question rather than saying that each of them are `person_1.ids` etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do :

```
person_1_ids = {id1: "1", id2: "2"}
person_2_ids = {id1: "3", id2: "4"}
person_3_ids = {id1: "5", id2: "6"}

hash = [person_1_ids,person_2_ids,person_3_ids].inject({}) do |out_hash,in_hash|
  out_hash.merge(in_hash) { |k,o,n| [o,n].join(',') }
end

hash # => {:id1=>"1,3,5", :id2=>"2,4,6"}
```

Comment: If you changed it following my comment, then sorry, it might be better to have `{}` as the initial value for `inject` as you originally did. Without it, it will work, but it will have side effects on the given hash.

Answer (score 0):

```
person_1_ids = {id1: "1", id2: "2"}
person_2_ids = {id1: "3", id2: "4"}
person_3_ids = {id1: "5", id2: "6"}

(person_1_ids.to_a + person_2_ids.to_a + person_3_ids.to_a).group_by{|a| a.first}.each_with_object({}){|h, obj| obj[h.first] = h.last.transpose.last.join(",")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler (easy to understand) version of doing the same thing:

```
person_1_ids = {id1: "1", id2: "2"}
person_2_ids = {id1: "3", id2: "4"}
person_3_ids = {id1: "5", id2: "6"}

hash = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = []}

[person_1_ids,person_2_ids,person_3_ids].each do |h| 
  h.keys.each do |k|
    hash[k] << h[k]
  end
end

persons = {}

hash.keys.each do |k|
  persons[k] = hash[k].join(",")
end

puts persons #{:id1=>"1,3,5", :id2=>"2,4,6"}
```